# pip install graphite on ubuntu 14.04 giving error

Tags: graphite

pip install graphite is giving following error :

```
 warning: no files found matching 'tools/py3tool.py'
 warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'doc/f2py'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
 Downloading/unpacking piddle>=1.0.15 (from graphite)
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement piddle>=1.0.15 (from graphite)    (from versions: 0.2.dev.linux-x86_64, 0.3.dev) 
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for piddle>=1.0.15 (from graphite)
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04 you can install graphite from package.

Install graphite-web

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphite-web
```

[Install whisper](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/install.html)

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-whisper
```

Install carbon

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphite-carbon
```

You could also use [script](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/54007/Install-Graphite-on-Ubuntu-14-04):
but except using

```
rm /etc/apache2/000-default.conf
```

you should use command

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for fedora systems:

```
pip-python install carbon whisper graphite-web
```

Install dependencies:

```
# pip-python install django django-tagging
# https://github.com/graphite-project/ceres/ (Not sure why this was needed       in spite of whisper being present)
# Check if anything else python check-dependencies.py (from a source checkout)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the 'graphite' package on PyPI is not what you'd expect but a dead package(?) from 2009. Installing graphite-web, carbon and whisper using pip does what you want, e.g.

```
pip install graphite-web carbon whisper
```